# 6px difference between Firefox and Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox, pixel

I've integrated an image to line up with and other image at the top (lines)and there is 6px difference in Firefox compare to Chrome or Safari. I don't understand where the difference comes from since all my other images (lines) are lining up perfectly in all browsers. [my website: beta.zenniel.ca](http://beta.zenniel.ca/#np-1489)

Here is my css:

```
.BlogueTop  {
  float: right;
  background: url(http://beta.zenniel.ca/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/blogueTop.jpg) no-repeat;
  width: 12px;
  height: 268px;
  margin: -269px 79px 0px 0px;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
}
```

By the way, the image at the top is the same place in Firefox and Chrome (140px from the right).

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Just a side note: Your "clientèle" menu option does not seem to work. In-case you were unaware.

Comment: I really like that design :) It would be better if you replaced those decoration `<img>`s with CSS background images. It would also solve some of these cross-browser issues.

Comment: Thanks level42, I didn't notice it!

Comment: misterManSam: It is a background image in css the image that is bugging in firefox! and thanks for the comment on the design, your help is really appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

at top of your .css file add

```
*{
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: I've tried it, it doesn't change remove the 6px extra in Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

Each browser does have his own default values. Therefore there are css files that set all default values of the browsers to your own default values. Such css files you can find on the web.

Here's an example: http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

Comment: Would like to note reset.css essentially removes all styles from everything. If you would like to keep standard stuff (e.g. bold on headings), [normalize.css](http://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/) might be a better option - not to mention that normalize.css is an actively maintined project with a lot of support

Comment: I had the css reset file and I've changed it gor the normalize.css but still having the 6px problem in firefox :(

Comment: Added before your main style?

Comment: I've integrated like this:
`code`
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en-US">

<head>        
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />        
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" />
        <title>Zenniel Marketing | </title>
        <link rel='stylesheet'  href='http://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/3.0.1/normalize.css' type='text/css' media='all' />`code`

And nothing changed

Comment: @Zenniel That's not the right link. Try <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/3.0.1/normalize.css" type="text/css" media="all">

Comment: @Callie, strangly enough, there is the http:// in the source code but this forum removed it but I confirm, it is there. This bug is a nightmare (I've tried everything in the past week and nothing works).

Answer (score 0):

Why not changing your margin to this

```
.BlogueTop  {
    background: url("http://beta.zenniel.ca/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/blogueTop.jpg") no-repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    border: 0 none;
    float: right;
    height: 268px;
    margin: -269px 84px 0 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 12px;
}
```

instead of this

```
.BlogueTop  {
  float: right;
  background: url(http://beta.zenniel.ca/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/blogueTop.jpg) no-repeat;
  width: 12px;
  height: 268px;
  margin: -269px 79px 0px 0px;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
}
```

Comment: It shifts `6px` to left in firefox

Comment: It shift the margin but now it's not align in Firefox and Chrome. I was hoping someone knew a trick for Firefox bug without changing the margin in general because it's align in Chrome and Safari. :(

The mystery continue...

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue.
Setting line-height: 0px worked for me.